# Swagger Code generation error

Tags: swagger

Some help needed i was trying to generate the swagger client code using the command for an Expedia mobile API

```
java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i https://www.expedia.co.jp/static/mobile/swaggerui/swagger.json -l java -o samples/client/expedia
```

The code generation fails with the following error

**[main] ERROR io.swagger.codegen.languages.JavaClientCodegen - No Type defined for Property null Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate model
'detailedRentalFare'**

The type attribute within the DetailedRentalFare is where it fails. I am not sure why this fails since the data type is defined. I am newbie to Swagger any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please open an issue at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues with the spec for reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by @wing328

the issue is caused by incorrect type for array, e.g.

```
"detailedRentalFare": {
  "properties": {
    "rateTerm": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "It can have the following values: HOURLY, DAILY, WEEKLY, WEEKEND, MONTHLY, TOTAL, TRIP"
    },
    "rate": {
      "$ref": "mobilePrice"
    },
    "priceBreakdownOfTotalDueToday": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "rentalFareBreakdownItem"
      }
    },
```

It should be

```
     "items": {
        "$ref": "rentalFareBreakdownItem"
      }
```

or even better

```
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "$ref": "rentalFareBreakdownItem"
      }
```

After correcting this i was able to generate the code.

Comment: Link to the actual issue  https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/1388

Answer (score 1):

From [@wing328](http://github.com/wing328)'s answer, even if this isn't your service to fix, you can still generate a client from it.

First, just download the JSON locally:
`wget https://www.expedia.co.jp/static/mobile/swaggerui/swagger.json > expedia.json`

Next, modify the value in the JSON that @wing328 pointed out

Finally, rerun your codegen using the static file as the source:

```
java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate \
   -i ./expedia.json \
   -l java \
   -o samples/client/expedia
```

It's always nice to let the service owner know about the issue, too, since fixing it will help with their adoption of the api.